# Azure Function App (Python) has constant Azure-related info logs and warnings related to blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a simple python function. It runs every 4 hours, and puts a message on the queue.

```
@app.function_name(name="Example")
@app.schedule(schedule="0 0 */4 * * *", arg_name="myTimer")
@app.queue_output(arg_name="msg", queue_name=queue_name, connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")
def my_function(myTimer: func.TimerRequest, msg: func.Out[typing.List[str]]) -> None:
    msg.set('Example Message')
    logging.info(f'Function run')
```

My host.json is also quite straightforward.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Warning",
      "Function": "Information",
      "Host": "Error",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Information",
      "Azure.Core": "Error"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "console": {
      "isEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

If I go into the Function App -> Log Stream I can see logs such as the below, that occurs every 15 minutes or so (the app should only run every 4 hours).

```
[Warning]   Error response [.] 409 The specified container already exists. (00.0s)
```

I also have a significant number of info level logs that seem to occur every few seconds.

```
[Information]   Request [] PUT https://[storagename].blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-hosts/locks/[appname]/host?comp=lease
```

Is this normal, or have I misconfigured my app?

I've searched this on google and added the host rules to filter these logs out of application insights, but I'm not sure whether they should even be shown in the log stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Container Already Exists Warning

The warning about the container already existing (409 The specified container already exists.) is likely related to the Azure Functions runtime trying to ensure that certain resources (like a container for locks) are available. This is a common operation and usually not something to worry about unless it's causing actual issues in your function's execution.

### Request Logs for Blob Storage

The frequent information logs (`PUT https://[storagename].blob.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-hosts/locks/[appname]/host?comp=lease`) are related to the Azure Functions host managing leases on blobs in the storage account. These leases are used to handle distributed locking when managing triggers and function executions, especially in consumption plans where multiple instances of the function might be running. This is normal behavior for Azure Functions.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanations. I'm surprised that there's so much background activity happening on a function that's only scheduled to run every 4 hours.